# Get frame to Hikvision IP Camera in python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, ip-camera

I have the next Hikvision IP Camera http://www.hikvision.com/es/Products_accessries_161_i11969.html I configured it in my local network and I have connection with the browser and I can see the camera working perfectly. I have searched in different post to get frame in cameras like this, but I can't do it. Here I put the code that I used to try it and the response. 
I want to obtain a frame and save it in my destock to processed after.

```
import cv2
import requests
import numpy as np
import urllib
import hikvision.api
import requests
import shutil

#Donwload from: https://github.com/fbradyirl/hikvision/archive/master.zip

hik_camera = hikvision.api.CreateDevice('192.168.1.64', username='admin', password=contrasenia)
"""
INFO:hikvision.api:Initialising new hikvision camera client
INFO:hikvision.api:motion_url: http://192.168.1.64/MotionDetection/1
INFO:hikvision.api:ElementTree.register_namespace: http://www.hikvision.com/ver10/XMLSchema
INFO:hikvision.api:Going to probe device to test connection
INFO:hikvision.api:url: http://192.168.1.64/System/deviceInfo
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.1.64
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /System/deviceInfo HTTP/1.1" 200 696
DEBUG:hikvision.api:response: <Response [200]>
DEBUG:hikvision.api:status_code 200
DEBUG:hikvision.api:element_to_query: .//{http://www.hikvision.com/ver10/XMLSchema}firmwareVersion result: <Element '{http://www.hikvision.com/ver10/XMLSchema}firmwareVersion' at 0x7fb090b76cc8>
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.1.64
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET /MotionDetection/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 407
DEBUG:hikvision.api:Response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MotionDetection version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.hikvision.com/ver10/XMLSchema">
<id>1</id>
<enabled>false</enabled>
<regionType>grid</regionType>
<Grid>
<rowGranularity>18</rowGranularity>
<columnGranularity>22</columnGranularity>
</Grid>
<MotionDetectionRegionList>
<sensitivityLevel>0</sensitivityLevel>
</MotionDetectionRegionList>
</MotionDetection>

INFO:hikvision.api:Current motion detection state? enabled: false
WARNING:hikvision.api:sensitivityLevel is 0.
INFO:hikvision.api:sensitivityLevel now set to 1
INFO:hikvision.api:Connected OK!
INFO:hikvision.api:Camera firmaward version: V5.4.3
INFO:hikvision.api:Motion Detection enabled: False
"""

#The method:
"""
hik_camera.__class__(                    hik_camera.__setattr__(
hik_camera.__delattr__(                  hik_camera.__sizeof__(
hik_camera.__dict__                      hik_camera.__str__(
hik_camera.__dir__(                      hik_camera.__subclasshook__(
hik_camera.__doc__                       hik_camera.__weakref__
hik_camera.__eq__(                       hik_camera._base
hik_camera.__format__(                   hik_camera._host
hik_camera.__ge__(                       hik_camera._password
hik_camera.__getattribute__(             hik_camera._sensitivity_level
hik_camera.__gt__(                       hik_camera._username
hik_camera.__hash__(                     hik_camera._xml_namespace
hik_camera.__init__(                     hik_camera.disable_motion_detection(
hik_camera.__le__(                       hik_camera.enable_motion_detection(
hik_camera.__lt__(                       hik_camera.get_about(
hik_camera.__module__                    hik_camera.get_version(
hik_camera.__ne__(                       hik_camera.is_motion_detection_enabled(
hik_camera.__new__(                      hik_camera.motion_url
hik_camera.__reduce__(                   hik_camera.put_motion_detection_xml(
hik_camera.__reduce_ex__(                hik_camera.xml_motion_detection_off
hik_camera.__repr__(                     hik_camera.xml_motion_detection_on
"""
hik_camera
#<hikvision.api.CreateDevice object at 0x7fb09183ab38>
```

With this code I can´t obtain a frame.

Other options:

```
camera = requests.get('http://192.168.1.64', auth=('admin', contrasenia), stream=True)
#INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.1.64
#DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 480
chunk = camera.iter_content(chunk_size=1024)
chunk
#<generator object iter_slices at 0x7fb090b7a150>
bytes += bytes()
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'type' and 'bytes'
```

Other:

```
stream = urllib.request.urlopen("http://192.168.1.64")
#<http.client.HTTPResponse object at 0x7fb090b82320>
```

Other:

```
out_cv2 = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.64')
#<VideoCapture 0x7fb090b6dc10>
cv2.imshow(out_cv2)
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#TypeError: Required argument 'mat' (pos 2) not found
ret, frame = out_cv2.read()
cv2.imshow('out', frame)
#OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 304
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:304: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
ret
#False
frame
#
```

Other:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requ = requests.get('http://192.168.1.64', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', contrasenia), stream=True)
out_file = open('img.png', 'wb')
shutil.copyfileobj(requ.raw, out_file)
#The file is empty
```

This code is from other post with similar problem but I can't use it to get my objetive. What can I do?

Comment: I can download an image with the command:

"Wget -r -P ./ -A jpg, jpeg, * 'http: // admin: PASSWORD@192.168.1.64/Streaming/channels/1/picture'"

But I need to get this image in python, in real time, and I can't connect to the url that I have indicated. How could I do it? I have tried with urllib libraries but the error is that it is not nonnumeric port, in addition, urllib3 has not been possible either. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your camera settings (network configuration) and check de rtsp port, in my case is 555.

I have a hikvision DS-2CD2D14WD, in my case I had to use the following:

rtsp://yourusername:yourpassword@172.16.30.248:555/Streaming/channels/2/

You can test your configuration in a program like VLC player.

The path after the IP address can change depending of your model, check
this page for other hikvision models:

https://www.ispyconnect.com/man.aspx?n=Hikvision  .

I recomend you to check this github page:

https://github.com/JFF-Bohdan/pynvr.git

Please, Let me know if this information works for you.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture()
cap.open("rtsp://yourusername:yourpassword@172.16.30.248:555/Streaming/channels/2/")

while(True):
     # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',ret)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It saved my day!!

Answer (score 3):

I get this on hikvisionapi-PyPI

```
from hikvisionapi import Client
import cv2
import time

cam = Client('http://192.168.1.10', 'admin', 'Astra123', timeout=30)
cam.count_events = 2 # The number of events we want to retrieve (default = 1)
response = cam.Streaming.channels[102].picture(method='get', type='opaque_data')
with open('screen.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        if chunk:
            f.write(chunk)

time.sleep(1)
img = cv2.imread('screen.jpg')
cv2.imshow("show", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be the one you are looking for.

```
    import cv2
    import requests
    import numpy as np
    from hikvisionapi import Client

    cam = Client('http://192.168.1.10', 'admin', 'Astra123')
    while True:
        print("starting picture capture")
        vid = cam.Streaming.channels[102].picture(method ='get', type = 'opaque_data')
        
        bytes = b''
        with open('screen.jpg', 'wb') as f:
            for chunk in vid.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
    
                bytes += chunk
                a = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8')
                b = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9')
                if a != -1 and b != -1:
                    jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
                    bytes = bytes[b+2:]
                    i = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
                    cv2.imshow('i', i)
                    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                        break
                
        if cv2.waitKey(0) == 27:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

I had one problem in my pc, opencv had some problem with the version. Now, i had opencv 3.2 and I can do the next line:

```
cv2.VideoCapture("rstp://admin:PASSWORD@192.168.1.64/doc/page/previw.asp")
```

and I can take frames.